# Entity Framework - Error 3007 Mapping Relationship - Foreign Key

Tags: c#, entity-framework, foreign-keys, constraints

I have two tables, BookmakerTeamNames and XMLSoccer-Team.

The relationship is:
BookmakerTeamNames 0/1 to 1 XMLSoccer-Team

They are linked based on TeamID in Table SoccerTeam and XMLSoccerTeamID in BookmakerTeamNames.

When I validate my model in EF Designer, I receive error 3007 : Problem in mapping fragments starting at line xxx. Column(s) XMLSoccerTeamID are being mapped in both fragments to different conceptual side properties.

The relationship doesn't exist in my database, as the FK constraint disallows me from having a NULL value. Hence, the reason for trying to add this association.

Thanks in advance

Comment: EDIT: I have this working now, but I've had to remove the foreign key from the entity. Is this correct?

Comment: I was able to delete all tables, mangle the names of the referencing side, and re-import to solve the 3007.  Not adding as an answer because its seems your ID's names already do not match.

Answer (score 0):

To view the SQL Server error log
In Object Explorer, expand a server, expand Management, and then expand SQL Server Logs.
Right-click a log and click View SQL Server Log.
so you can find exact reason about the error.

Comment: The error is received in the EF designer. See my comment above, I may have fixed it but I'm not too sure

Comment: Which is the  datatype for that  field